# Is there a free Google classroom plugin allowing coding assigment in javascript, python, java or other

Tags: google-classroom

As a teacher, I would like to extend google classroom with a virtual coding platform (as CodeRunner on Moodle) :

- Students are asked to write program code to some specification
- Code is then graded by running it in a series of tests.
- I've tried the moodle codeRunner plugin. But this is realy not user friendly for teachers
- I also tried CodeHS which is a plugin for google classroom : but it look like theacher cannot design their own exercices, unless you pay the licence